# Are the notations $p(x)dx$ and $p(dx)$ equivalent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have the following notation

$$p_{Y \mid U}(y \mid U) = \int p_{Y\mid X}(y \mid x) \ p_{x \mid U}(dx \mid U) $$

The article says that if I want to approximate $p_{Y \mid U}(y \mid U) $ I can compute

$$\hat{p}_{Y \mid U}(y \mid U) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}p_{Y\mid X}(y \mid x_i),$$ where $x_i$ are sampled from the distribution with PDF $p_{x \mid U}(x \mid U)$.

Now suppose I have (in another source)

$$p_{Y \mid U}(y \mid U)=\int p_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x)p_{X \mid U}(x \mid U)dx$$

Is this notation equivalent, so I can use the approximation above?

Comment: Writing $p(x)\,\mathrm dx$ suggests $p$ is a function whereas the notation $p(\,\mathrm dx)$ suggests $p$ is a measure.

Comment: @StefanHansen Thank you! But if the density exists (which is true in both cases and is used in the first example) - can we say that both expressions for conditional probability are true and the approximation can be used in the second case?

Comment: If the measure $p_{X\mid U}(\cdot\mid U)$ admits a density (with respect to the Lebesgue measure), and let's denote that by $x\mapsto f_{X\mid U}(x\mid U)$ to avoid confusion, then $\int g(x)\, p_{X\mid U}(\mathrm dx\mid U)=\int g(x) f_{X\mid U}(x\mid U)\,\mathrm dx$. This is an immediate consequence of the very definition of admitting a density.

Comment: @StefanHansen You helped me! Please, one more question to clarify it: searching my first source I have just found that it seems they construct this measure as a limit of $$\hat{p}_{X\mid U}(dx \mid U) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\delta_{x_i}(dx), $$ where $\delta_{x_i}()$ is a [Dirac measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure) at points $x_k$ sampled from the corresponding density (again, their notation is little bit different). And they claim that after satisfying boundary conditions we can set $$p_{X\mid U}(dx \mid U) :=p_{X\mid U}(x \mid U)dx$$

Comment: Doesn't really make sense to use $p_{X\mid U}(\cdot\mid U)$ to denote two different objects.